# How do I insert an element into XML using Linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

My XML:

```
<content>
    <item id="1">A</item>
    <item id="2">B</item>
    <item id="4">D</item>
</content>
```

I have loaded this using XML similar to:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(data.Value);
var items = from i in xDoc.Element("content").Elements("item")
    select i;
```

I want to insert another element, to end up with something like:

```
<content>
    <item id="1">A</item>
    <item id="2">B</item>
    <item id="3">C</item>
    <item id="4">D</item>
</content>
```

How do I do this using Linq2Xml?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
xDoc.Element("content")
    .Elements("item")
    .Where(item => item.Attribute("id").Value == "2").FirstOrDefault()
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", "C", new XAttribute("id", "3")));
```

Or, if you like XPath like I do:

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("content/item[@id = '2']")
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", "C", new XAttribute("id", "3")));
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you :) My only question now is where is the XPathSelectElement? I can't seem to find it in any of the namespaces I'm using. (I'm using System.Linq and System.Xml.Linq)

Comment: XPathSelectElement is in System.Xml.XPath