# LINQ to create new records in a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

### Question

I have a simiar **XML** file stored in my physical drive , how i can create a  new record using C# in this `xml` file ? , is it possible to do it with **LINQ**? or is there an any other method ?

[other method should not be read the whole file and concat and save back using a `filestream`]

---

### Sample XML:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <price>1150</price>
  </product>
</prodcuts>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131061/how-do-i-insert-an-element-into-xml-using-linq ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

There a great answer about the subject here: [XDocument or XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is posiible do with LINQ look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx)