# How can I insert an XElement into an existing xml-file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I do have following xml:

```
<Assembly>
  <Bench>
    <Typ>P1</Typ>
    <DUT>
       <A>6</A>
     </DUT>
  </Bench>
  <Bench>
    <Typ>P2</Typ>
     <DUT>
       <A>6</A>
     </DUT>
  </Bench>
</Assembly>
```

How can I get a reference to 'P2'-element that I can insert a new DUT? I tried following code which gives me an error:

```
var xElement = xmlDoc.Element("Assembly")
                                .Elements("Bench")
                                .Where(item => item.Attribute("Typ").Value == "P2")
                                .FirstOrDefault();

xElement.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("DUT"));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: use mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131061/how-do-i-insert-an-element-into-xml-using-linq

Comment: @Andrew: that xElement is null

Comment: -> In which way I need to change the query? The example does not give me right solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Typ` is element name, not an attribute. If you meant to add new `<DUT>` element after existing `<DUT>` under the second `<Bench>`, this slight change to the code you've tried should work :

```
var xElement = xmlDoc.Element("Assembly")
                     .Elements("Bench")
                     .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Element("Typ").Value == "P2");

xElement.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("DUT"));
```

Comment: You could shorten it a bit by incorporating the lambda into the `FirstOrDefault` call and removing the `Where`

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the same thing, just to show the options available.

```
XElement typ = xmlDoc.Descentants("Typ")
                     .FirstOrDefault(typ => ((string)typ) == "P2");
```

You can use the same `AddAfterSelf` as har07, or `.Parent.Add()` if it doesn't matter where in the parent Bench it goes.  `Add` will add it as the last element.

```
typ.Parent.Add(new XElement("DUT"));
```