# How to add attributes to an element using LINQ, C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XElement object which has a number of attributes and I simply want to add another attribute to the element.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
xElement.Add(new XAttribute("Foo", "Bar"));
```

Answer (score 4):

To create an element with an attribute use:

`var xmlTest = new XElement("XmlElementName", new XAttribute("XmlAttributeName", "AttributeValue"));`