# c# White space in XElement

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create XML request like this:

```
<PosXML version="7.2.0">
<ReadCardRequest>
<Amount>10</Amount>
<CurrencyName>EUR</CurrencyName>
</ReadCardRequest>
</PosXML>
```

I have problem with PosXML line. It works only when to use simply PosXML but gets error when it is PosXML version="7.2.0"

My code right now:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("PosXML",
                                          new XElement("ReadCardRequest",
                                              new XElement("Amount", summa.ToString()),
                                              new XElement("CurrencyName", "EUR"))));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking. Do you want the `version="7.2.0"` to be included in your document? Then you need to add `new XAttribute("version", "7.2.0")` inside the `PosXML` element.

Comment: You seem to have some trouble understanding XML. I can recommend you to read through this [simple tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) to get some basic knowledge of XML and its parts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454390/how-to-add-attributes-to-an-element-using-linq-c

Answer (score 2):

You can use an XAttribute for that:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("PosXML",
                                  new XElement("ReadCardRequest",
                                      new XElement("Amount", "1"),
                                           new XElement("CurrencyName", "EUR")),
                                  new XAttribute("version","7.2.0")));
```

(As poke also pointed out)